# JQuery Json Result Data Object. ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am calling an MVC action method which returns data as a Json string. One Key has a value = '5S'
I cannot access this using the following **data.5S** because it does not like a alphanumeric values that start with a number. Is there a way to access the key/value pair without referencing a key name? I need the key value and the value also. I need to get both back.
Can O do something like var myvalue1 = data[i][0] ; myvalue2 = data[i][1]

Here is my call to the action method

```
$.get('/Home/GetTypes', function (data) {
        alert(data.KAIZ);
    });
```

Comment: Its not valid JSON then. JSON parsers will complain in converting the string to JSON.

Comment: Keys can start with numbers just fine in JSON, according to http://jsonlint.com.

@Nate: What's wrong with data["5S"]?

Comment: I was doing data.5S. I did not know other syntax. Data["5S"] works. Do you know if I could somehow loop through the whole dataset and get the key and value ? More like a two column array? I want to use the data to render buttons.